# Update where select, guarantee atomicity

Tags: sql, t-sql, atomic

I have a T-SQL query like this:

```
UPDATE 
    [MyTable]
SET
    [MyField] = @myValue
WHERE
    [Id] = 
    (
        SELECT TOP(1) 
            [Id]
        FROM
            [MyTable]
        WHERE
            [MyField] IS NULL
            -- AND other conditions on [MyTable]
        ORDER BY
            [Id] ASC
    )
```

It seems that this query is not atomic (the select of 2 concurrent executions can return the same Id twice).

Edit:
If I execute this query, the Id returned by the SELECT will not be available for the next execution (because [MyField] will not be NULL anymore). However, if I execute this query twice at the same time, both executions could return the same Id (and the second UPDATE would overwrite the first one).

I've read that one solution to avoid that is to use a **SERIALIZABLE** isolation level. Is that the best / fastest / most simple way ?

Comment: What you mean seems? That should return only one value. Unless you use `WITH TIES` option.

Comment: `the select can return the same Id twice` . Mmm, it will prorbably always return the same id.

Comment: @sagi not if the update is executed.

Comment: That is a very different question. Let me work on it.

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `UPDLOCK` would be enough

Comment: @RuslanK. That works perfectly. Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can see, `UPDLOCK` would be enough (test code confirms that)

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the max ID first then use it in a cross join for the the update.

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/NOPI54063)**

```
WITH cte as (
    SELECT TOP 1 ID
    FROM [MyTable]
    WHERE MYFIELD IS NULL
    ORDER BY ID
)
UPDATE t
SET [ID] = cte.[ID]
FROM [MyTable] t
CROSS JOIN  cte;
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: @DerrickMoeller Yes, I realize that after finish the query. That is why I request sample data and expected output. But the idea is there.

Answer (score 0):

This would result the top 1 value but if its the same you have the potential to return more than one value.

Try using DISTINCT

I understand that top(1) should only return 1 row but the question states its returning more than one row. So i thought it might be because the value is the same. So you could possibly use something like this

```
    SELECT DISTINCT TOP 1 name FROM [Class];
```

Its either that or where clause to narrow results

Comment: TOP 1 will only return one row.

Comment: I thought it just returns the top row? So what if that row is the same?

Comment: If the row is the same? I'm not understanding your point, DISTINCT will return multiple values. That doesn't appear to be his intent.

Comment: Unless you use `WITH TIES` only return a row Check [**demo**](http://rextester.com/RDEU64575).  Anyway the OP question is a very different one.

Comment: Again read the question after edit. The problem is one update affect the next one.